# Почему не добавляется класс open при клике (js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я новичок в js и мало что умею.
Не так давно делал модальное окно(pop up) на сайте с помощью js
хотел с помощью такого же кода сделать всплывающий элемент при нажатии на div
В итоге при нажатии на div ничего не происходит, ошибки в консоли даже нет.
при ручном добавлении класса open в браузере всплывающее окно появляется, может не так что-то с кодом?

html

```
        <div class="questions" id="first-question">
            <span class="play" id="first-question-text">Как начать играть?</span>
            <img src="icons/arrow_drop_down.png" id="arrow-drop">
             <div class="reply" id="reply1">
                <span class="reply-text" id="text-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </div>
```

css

```
.questions{
    background-color: rgba(166, 149, 101, 0.50);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.questions:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#arrow-drop{
    width: 35px;
    height: 32px;
    fill: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 395px;
}

#reply{
    visibility: hidden;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(166, 149, 101, 0.50);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    
}
#reply.open{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

js

```
 document.getElementById("first-question").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("reply1").classList.add("open")
})

document.getElementById("first-question").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("reply1").classList.remove("open")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас класс `open` при клике добавляется и сразу удаляется.

Используйте `classList.toggle` вместо двух `classList.add("open")` и `classList.remove("open")`

```
document.getElementById("first-question").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("reply1").classList.toggle("open")
})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сильно выручили, с каждым днем открытий все больше. Сначала ваш скрипт не работал, пока я не создал новый js файл и в нем не прописал. Почему то думал что 1 файл можно прикреплять к разным html документам в одном проекте, как с css